# JQuery/Ajax post to php breaks JQuery/Js code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

```
    var hiScore = 0;
    var userip;

    function onGameOver(){
    if (-1 < score && score < 6) { doStuff(); }
    if (5 < score && score < 9) { doStuff2(); }
    if (8 < score && score < 15) { doStuff3(); }
    if (14 < score && score < 21) { doStuff4(); }           
    if (20 < score && score < 27) { doStuff5(); }
    if (26 < score && score < 31) { doStuff6(); }
    if (30 < score && score < 36) { doStuff7(); }
    if (35 < score && score < 51) { doStuff8(); }
    if (50 < score && score < 69) { doStuff9(); }
    PostTo();
    }

    function PostTo() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'Score.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{hiScore:hiScore,
              userip:userip},
        success:function(data){
        alert('Success');
    }
    });
    }
```

the `$.ajax` part of the code seems to break the js code. I've no idea why. Maybe I'm using it wrong. 
here is the php as well.

```
<?php

$hiScore = $_POST['hiScore'];
$userip = $_POST['userip'];
$file = fopen('file.txt','w+');
fwrite($file, $hiScore.'\t'.$userip);
fclose($file);

?>
```

Any idea what is going on? 
The code starts working again perfectly after I remove the post code.

How it breaks: obviously there is more to the code its a game simply put the game doesn't start it just "breaks".

Code edited

It still isn't posting to the file.txt file. Thanks to baao for pointing out mistakes!

Comment: Explain how it is breaking.

Comment: seems like I forgot the bracket in my other answer. I've corrected it for you... :)

Comment: `<?php?` is invalid, as is the closing `>`. In the Javascript, the `score` variable is never defined. Did you mean `hiScore`? You should pass things as arguments, instead of using global variables. Global variables are a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function PostTo() {
$.ajax({
    url:'src/Score.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{hiScore:hiScore,
          userip:userip},
    success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    } // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<you have forgotten the closing bracket here 
});
}
```

---

it is `<?php`, not `<php?` to open php; to close php you need `?>` not `>`

```
<?php // <<<<< here 

$hiScore = $_POST['hiScore'] ? $_POST['hiScore'] : 'not set';
$userip = $_POST['userip'] ? $_POST['userip'] : 'not set';
$file = fopen('file11111111.txt','a+');
fwrite($file, 'Score: '.$hiScore.' IP is: '.$userip.' '.PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
echo "I was here!";

?>  // <<<<<< and here
```

---

```
if (-1 < score && score < 6) { doStuff(); }       //  |
if (5 < score && score < 9) { doStuff2(); }       //  |
if (8 < score && score < 15) { doStuff3(); }      //  | 
if (14 < score && score < 21) { doStuff4(); }     //  |     
if (20 < score && score < 27) { doStuff5(); }     //  |||||| should all be hiScore?!?
if (26 < score && score < 31) { doStuff6(); }     //  |
if (30 < score && score < 36) { doStuff7(); }     //  |
if (35 < score && score < 51) { doStuff8(); }     //  |
if (50 < score && score < 69) { doStuff9(); }     //  |
```